# Camel example can't find org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I've created a small Apache Camel example, but it can't find the class `org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/NJDs9KQz) the full error log.

I've looked the class up on [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent), which says it should be contained in `org.apache.camel:camel-core`. Adding it does not solve my problem.
What's wrong in this example?

---

This is the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

and here the route.

```
@Component
public class ZmqRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        //from("stream:in").to("stream:out");

        String host = "zmq.devnet.iota.org";
        from("zeromq:tcp://" + host + ":5556?socketType=SUBSCRIBE&topics=tx")
                .to("stream:out")
                .log("${body}");
    }
}
```

Lastly, here the `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    java
    application
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

application {
    mainClassName = "org.example.camel.Application"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("-Xlint:all"))
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {
    val camelVersion = "3.0.0-M1"

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:$camelVersion")

    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-stream-starter:$camelVersion")

    //implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-core:$camelVersion")

    implementation("org.apache-extras.camel-extra:camel-zeromq:2.22.0") {
        exclude(module = "zeromq-scala-binding_2.10")
    }

    implementation("org.zeromq:jeromq:0.5.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, after looking at Camel Core `3.0.0.M1`, I discovered the `.class` file for

```
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent
```

doesn't exists anymore!

```
camel-core-3.0.0-M1.jar\org\apache\camel\impl
```

[image]

Honestly it seems like a bug to me, or incompatibility with `core-zeromq`.

Comment: `val camelVersion = "3.0.0-M1"` is in the line after `dependencies {`. I think I have (at least) most of the dependencies, because everything compiles just fine.

Comment: Np! Thx for trying to help :-)

Comment: @mike could you run the Gradle dependencies task and paste the output?

Comment: @mike downgrade the starter to 2.23.1 and let me know. Might solve it. The size of the Camel Core JAR for 3.0.0.m1 is suspiciously too small.

Comment: Thx, the error is gone! What dependencies do I need to add if I want to use version 3? Further, the application finishes directly after startup and does not 'wait' on the ZMQ endpoint. It's the same with the stream route I've commented out. Here a log: https://pastebin.com/KA7Xe6rp

Comment: @mike I'm trying to understand **who** actually is requiring that missing class.

Comment: @mike seems like a core-zeromq issue. Did you solve? I think the best is to downgrade to 2.23.1

Comment: Yes, the application starts up fine. But it shuts down after that. I assume that's because my code lacks sth.

Comment: You are using a mixed version of Came, eg 3.0 with 2.x from camel-zeromq. camel-zeromq is not Camel 3 compatible so use Camel 2.x. Also Camel 3 is in development and 3.0 is currently at milestone releases which is not intended for production.

Answer (score 2):

The class has been moved to  https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/DefaultComponent.java

so on a different package. This was reported also on the migration guide

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#migrating-custom-components