# camel-zeromq is not properly terminating JeroMQ context

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, zeromq, jeromq

I have created a small Apache Camel example, that uses the camel-zeromq component. JeroMQ is configured as ZMQ implementation.

Here an excerpt of `build.gradle.kts`

```
dependencies {
    // 3.0.0-M1, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55314360/1809463
    val camelVersion = "2.23.1"

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:$camelVersion")
    implementation("org.apache-extras.camel-extra:camel-zeromq:2.22.0") {
        exclude(group = "org.zeromq", module = "zeromq-scala-binding_2.10")
        exclude(group = "com.typesafe.akka", module = "akka-zeromq_2.10")
        exclude(group = "com.typesafe.akka", module = "akka-actor_2.10")
    }
    implementation("org.zeromq:jeromq:0.4.0") // versions > 0.4.0 don't work

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.apache.camel:camel-test:$camelVersion")
    testImplementation("org.apache.camel:camel-test-spring:$camelVersion")
}
```

Following two error occurs on shutdown when a `ShutdownStrategy` with a small timeout is set, otherwise no error is logged and the application does not terminate fully.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: null     at
>   zmq.Ctx.terminate(Ctx.java:198) ~[jeromq-0.4.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.term(ZMQ.java:316) ~[jeromq-0.4.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.apacheextras.camel.component.zeromq.Listener.stop(Listener.java:130)
>   ~[camel-zeromq-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]     at
>   org.apacheextras.camel.component.zeromq.ZeromqConsumer.doStop(ZeromqConsumer.java:63)
>   [camel-zeromq-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]

and

> java.lang.InterruptedException: null  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1253)
>   [na:1.8.0_40]     at
>   org.apacheextras.camel.component.zeromq.ZeromqProducer.stop(ZeromqProducer.java:122)
>   ~[camel-zeromq-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]

More details are available [here](https://pastebin.com/DnTgkS0J) and [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/510655628/log.txt). The project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mbe24/camel-jeromq).

Comment: Probably better to create an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL

Comment: You can log a ticket at the camel-extra github project at: https://github.com/camel-extra/camel-extra

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/camel-extra/camel-extra/issues/20